# Sign of the real part of a rational function

Tags: complex-numbers

I have been trying to verify this result; for $|z|>1$, is it true that $\Re\{\frac{1+z}{1-z}\}<0?$  Can anybody help me in getting the answer?

Comment: Can you determine the real part of $\frac{1+z}{1-z}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a+ib=\frac {1+x+iy}{1-x-iy}=\frac {(1+x+iy)(1-x+iy)}{(1-x-iy)(1-x+iy)}$

So $a+ib=\frac {1-x+iy+x-x^2+ixy+iy-ixy-y^2}{(1-x)^2+y^2}$

$a+ib=\frac {1-x^2-y^2+i2y}{(1-x)^2+y^2}$

$a=\frac {1-x^2-y^2}{(1-x)^2+y^2}=\frac {1-(x^2+y^2)}{1-2x+(x^2+y^2)}$

The constraint that $|z|>1$ means that $x^2+y^2>1$

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $\Re(w) = \frac{1}{2}(w+\bar w)$ for $\forall w \in \mathbb{C}$ so:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\Re\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right) & = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z} + \frac{1+\bar z}{1- \bar z}\right) \\
 & =\frac{1}{2}\;\frac{(1+z)(1-\bar z)+(1+\bar z)(1-z)}{|1-z|^2} = \\
 & =\frac{1}{2}\;\frac{1 - \cancel{\bar z} + \bcancel{z} - |z|^2 \;\;+\;\; 1 - \bcancel{z} + \cancel{\bar z} - |z|^2}{|1-z|^2} = \\
 & = \cdots
\end{align}
$$

Comment: How do you show the conjugate of $\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ is given by $\frac{1+\bar z}{1-\bar z}$?

Comment: @SimpleArt I assumed that by the time this question was asked it must have been established already that $\overline{a+b}=\bar a+\bar b$, $\overline{a \cdot b}=\bar a \cdot \bar b$ and $\overline{a / b}=\bar a / \bar b$. See for example [complex conjugate properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate#Properties).

Comment: Oh, I know what conjugates are, but I never really knew much about them.

Answer (score 2):

Let a complex number $z$ be $a+bi$. $${\frac{1+z}{1-z}}=\frac{(a+1)+bi}{(1-a)-bi}$$ Rationalizing this expression, we have $$\frac{((1+a)+bi)((1-a)+bi)}{(1-a)^2+b^2}$$ $$=\frac{(1-a^2-b^2)+2bi}{(1-a)^2+b^2}$$ $$=\frac{(1-(a^2+b^2))+2bi}{(1-a)^2+b^2}$$. The real part of $z$ is $$\frac{(1-(a^2+b^2))}{(1-a)^2+b^2}$$

Since $|z|>1$, $a^2+b^2>1$. This means that the numerator is negative. Also note that the denominator is positive because it is a sum of squares, at least one term of which ($b^2$ or $(1-a)^2$) is greater than zero.

Thus it shows that the real part of $z$ is negative.

Answer (score 0):

When $\exists\space\text{z}\in\mathbb{C}$:

$$\frac{1+\text{z}}{1-\text{z}}=\frac{\left(1+\text{z}\right)\times\overline{1-\text{z}}}{\left(1-\text{z}\right)\times\overline{1-\text{z}}}=\frac{\left(1-\text{z}\right)\times\overline{1-\text{z}}}{\left|1-\text{z}\right|^2}=\frac{1+\Im^2\left[\text{z}\right]-\Re^2\left[\text{z}\right]-2\Re\left[\text{z}\right]\Im\left[\text{z}\right]i}{\left(1-\Re\left[\text{z}\right]\right)^2+\Im^2\left[\text{z}\right]}$$

So, we get:

$$\Re\left[\frac{1+\text{z}}{1-\text{z}}\right]=\frac{1+\Im^2\left[\text{z}\right]-\Re^2\left[\text{z}\right]}{\left(1-\Re\left[\text{z}\right]\right)^2+\Im^2\left[\text{z}\right]}$$

And:

$$\left|\text{z}\right|=\sqrt{\Re^2\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im^2\left[\text{z}\right]}\space>1\space\space\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\space\Re^2\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im^2\left[\text{z}\right]\space>1$$

Comment: The computation is difficult to follow, and wrong from the second step on.

Comment: @upvoter Please explain your vote.